# CakePHP is interrupting images

Tags: image, cakephp, routes

I am using fckEditor as text editor. When i upload images thru it the images were uploaded to app/webroot/fckeditor/images.

And when they're embedded it looks like

/fckfiles/SalmonSashimi.jpg

Until now it looks right.

But the image doesn't appear.
So when I browse the image directly, at here

http://www.in-culture.info/fckfiles/SalmonSashimi.jpg

instead of displaying the URL, Cake *interrupts* the image call and trying to render it in a layout. I often face this error when I point .html file for iframe scroller and .xml file for flash embedding. This is really embarrassing

You can see the page here

http://www.in-culture.info/events/view/42

That image should appear before the text - "More" dont appear for short text.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved now.
It was not cake's fault.
I pointed incomplete absolute path at FckEditor so it didn't upload the files well.
However the uploader mistakenly passes the "OK" so the HTML tries to display it.
So cake tries to render something, as usual, when there is no physical file.

I spent about 10 hours to resolve this.
Now I don't hate cake as I did a few hours ago. (: :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the path where the images are saved. Instead of

```
/app/webroot/fckeditor/images
```

try to change to

```
/app/webroot/img/fckeditor/
```

I believe that it's possible.

Comment: Still the same http://www.in-culture.info/img/fckfiles/pegasus_theatre_logo_338A21.png

Comment: Are you sure that the file is there? Or is it possible to read it. Because when I call an image in my computer which is  in the correct path I can see it while if I write the fake image i.e. http://myserver/img/somethingnoththere.jpg I got also warnings on the page.

So check the physical existence of the file in that directory.